# How to add a third value to plotly so that row/observation ID-variable is shown on ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

**What I want to do**

I have a dataset, where each row has a unique ID, consisting of 8 digits fx 1234-5678. 
I am trying to plot two varaibles, a numeric variable and a categorial variable against eachother. However, I would like the unique ID for each value to be shown, when my mouse hovers over the observation in plotly.

**My troubles**

I have tried to add the ID-marker as a size, `size = ID`, but this doesn't work and R gives the warning message: "using size for a discrete variable is not advised." I have also tried it with color, where `color = ID`, but I would prefer that color was set to varaible A, `color = A`, as this is visually easier to look at and you can differentiate between the different values in A easier.

I am not sure how else to add the ID-marker, that serves no other purpose than to ID each obervation in a ggplotly output.

**Data example**

```
A <- c("Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "US", "US", "US", "US", "MENA", "MENA")
B<- c(0,3.15,4.55,5.02, 0,3.15,4.55,5.02, 0,3.15,4.55,5.02)
ID <- c("1234-5678", "1235-6789", "1345-6789", "1245-6789", "1224-5678", "1335-6789", "1445-6789", "1255-6789", "1234-5578", "1235-6689", "1335-6689", "1225-6889")

df <- data.frame(A,B,ID)

df_new <- df %>%
ggplot(aes(A,B, color=A))+
geom_point()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
theme(legend.position = "none")

ggplotly(df_new)
```

As you can see from the plot (once made), when you hover over the observations, the values from

I hope that someone can help me move forward from this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code as shown below. This will show the ID as the tooltip for each observation.

```
A <- c("Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "US", "US", "US", "US", "MENA", "MENA")
B<- c(0,3.15,4.55,5.02, 0,3.15,4.55,5.02, 0,3.15,4.55,5.02)
ID <- c("1234-5678", "1235-6789", "1345-6789", "1245-6789", "1224-5678", "1335-6789", "1445-6789", "1255-6789", "1234-5578", "1235-6689", "1335-6689", "1225-6889")

df <- data.frame(A,B,ID)

df_new <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(A,B, color=A, text = ID))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

ggplotly(df_new, tooltip = "text")
```